# Testing Android Application

Tags: android, testing, mobile

How do I test my Android application such that it works on all major android phones ? e.g. Motorola, HTC, Samsung etc.

I have an app that works on Nexus One and Samsung but it is giving problems on HTC Incredible.

Comment: Remember to upvote the people who help you! </nudge>

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's probably because the Nexus One and Samsung don't use the Sense UI, so it sounds like it's an issue on devices running the Sense UI.

I would recommend getting a cheap htc phone running the Sense UI (wildfire, hero, etc.), and testing it on that.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried a remote test service like perfectomobile ?  These services host real phones that you get remote access to for an hourly fee.

P.S. I'm sure there are others, and I'm not a shill.  I have however used them successfully.

I think Motorola has a similar service as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you actually have the devices nearby, it would be good to use automated testing, such as jUnit or Robotium on all of them. Especially Robotium seems like a good idea because technical bugs will show up in the Market anyway, but some buttons not showing due to different layouts on different devices will hardly not be reported at all.